# Operador ! em if ternário

Tags: php, operadores

Queria uma explicação sobre o uso do `!` no início do código.

```
$number = 28;

$resultado = !($number % 2) ? "O número é par" : "O número é ímpar";
echo $resultado;
```

Comment: ! É negação, exemplo !false é true, e !true é false. `!$a` **Verdadeiro se $a não é verdadeiro.**

Comment: Na teoria, o código sem o ! deveria voltar true "O número é par" , mas ele voltar como false quando tiro o !... Poderia me explicar o motivo por gentileza?

Comment: Operador ! e como uma informação que deu verdadeira, você força-se ela a ser falso..

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Em PHP, `1` e `0` são valores `truthy` e `falsy`, eles podem ser utilizados como condições lógicas, apesar de seus tipos serem diferentes de booleano.

No seu exemplo você tem `$number % 2`. Como o valor de `$number` é `28`, o resto dessa divisão será `0`, ou seja, é `falsy`, equivalente a `false` nesse caso de uso.

Logo ao fazer `$resultado = false ? "O número é par" : "O número é ímpar"`, `$resultado` estaria recebendo `O número é ímpar`, o que não é verdade, pois 28 é par.

Para resolver esse problema, você poderia inverter a sua expressão ternária, ou então inverter seu resultado.

Ou seja,

```
$resultado = $number % 2 ? "O número é ímpar" : "O número é par";
```

Ou então

```
$resultado = !($number % 2) ? "O número é par" : "O número é ímpar";
```

Nesse segundo caso, o resultado de `28 % 2`; `0`, que corresponde a um valor `falsy`, é negado, se tornando `true`, logo `$resultado` recebe `O número é par`, que é exatamente o que você quer.

Comment: Não é verdade que este valores booleanos sejam alias para os números 0 e 1.

Comment: Se você fizer `echo true`, o PHP imprime `1`, não?

Comment: E por que se fizer `2 == true` resulta em `true`? Então `true` também é alias para 2? E aí `true` é alias para qualquer valor que não for 0 ou uma forma de 0? [Documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) que não fala em alias, fala em conversão de valores. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxR9w.jpg E PHP não é JS também, por isso não usa os termos e definições colocados na resposta depois da edição, há implicações diferentes.

Comment: Se fizer `!($number % 3) ? "O número é múltiplo de 3" : "O número não é múltiplo de 3";` derruba toda a premissa de que 0 e 1 são valores especiais para serem utilizados como condições lógicas.

Comment: No [manual do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.boolean.php)  especifica que ao converter para booleano, os seguintes valores são considerados FALSE o próprio booleano FALSE,
os inteiros 0 e -0 (zero),
os pontos flutuantes 0.0 e -0.0 (zero),
uma string vazia e a string "0",
um array sem elementos,
o tipo especial NULL (incluindo variáveis não definidas),
objetos SimpleXML criados a partir de tags vazias

Comment: Qualquer outro valor é considerado TRUE (incluindo qualquer recurso e NAN).

Answer (score 10):

Neste código o uso do operador de negação é um erro ou pelo menos abuso. Mesmo que produza o resultado esperado não faz sentido e só não dá erro de execução porque PHP é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca.

O operador de negação pega um valor booleano, portanto falso ou verdadeiro e inverte seu valor.

O resultado de `$number % 2` é um número e não um booleano portanto não é correto aplicar o operador de negação nele. Funciona e em alguns casos pode produzir o que deseja, mas é confuso.

Em PHP qualquer o valor 0 (ou equivalente a 0) é sempre considerado falso e qualquer outro valor é considerado verdadeiro, então a linguagem faz uma coerção automática de tipo seguindo esta regra ([documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)).

Este é um caso que até funciona porque o resultado sempre será 0 ou 1 então a coerção funciona bem. Assim ficaria mais explícito qual é a condição que deseja que seja falsa ou verdadeira:

```
$number % 2 == 0 ? "O número é par" : "O número é ímpar";
```

Desta forma o código está bem claro que deseja que seja verdadeiro quando o resultado for 0, e sabemos que o resto de uma divisão por 2 sempre é 0 quando o número por par, se der 1 (portanto diferente de 0) é ímpar.

E se quiser mesmo usar o resultado como booleano não precisa fazer a negação:

```
$number % 2 ? "O número é ímpar" : "O número é par";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Operator/Conditional.php).

Raros os casos que a negação é necessária e útil, a não ser que venha de uma função que retorne um booleano, mas por uma expressão sempre dá pra construí-la de forma diferente para evitar o operador, ainda que nem sempre compense. Legibilidade para demonstrar a intenção é o que vem primeiro, tenha certeza que a negação ajudará entender melhor. Não é o caso demonstrado na pergunta.

Comment: Agora entendi, muito obrigada Maniero, ajudou demais. Estou estudando e não encontrava  sentido na resposta por nada. Agora tudo ficou mais claro.

Comment: @Aline só para confirmar, você escolheu a resposta que mais lhe ajudou? Você pode escolher qualquer uma, mas não pode escolher mais de uma. Eu notei que escolheu uma e depois mudou para outra. A que fica escolhida é sempre a última que escolher. È como um *radion button*, quando escolhe uma desliga a outra. Muitas pessoas trocam sem notar. È importante manter escolhida a que lhe ajudou mias, se foi a outra ok, mas se foi acidente, mense em trocar.